# Stuck on grub screen

Tags: keyboard, dual-boot, grub

Last week I Dualbooted elementary OS alongside windows, and it worked perfectly fine. Today, when I wanted to boot my pc, it got stuck on a grub command line screen. My keyboard doesn't work, I can't press <kbd>f2</kbd> to get in the bios.

The keyboard does work on other computers, so it's not hardware related. When I put a usb stick in the light in the usb doesn't light up. How can I start my pc?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

IF

- your keyboard is USB,
- and it doesn't respond during BIOS POST (i.e. before GRUB screen),
- and your USB stick doesn't seem to work too,

THEN

- the issue might be BIOS-related. Presumably, 'USB Legacy Support' (or some other USB support) has been disabled.

Possible workarounds:

- use PS/2 keyboard to access BIOS and check its 'Integrated Peripherals > USB controllers / USB Legacy Support' settings,
- [reset CMOS](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-clear-cmos-2624545), thus restoring your BIOS to its default settings.